# How to assign selected option's text to another model while using ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, model, ng-options

I can create a select tag and place data inside it. I can assign that select's selected option to a model but can't assign its text to another model.

Here is example below and **[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/507zzvmk/1/)**

**html:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
      <select ng-model="customerId" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in content" ng-change="customerName = item.name">
</select>
      <br/>
      <input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customerId"/>
      <input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customerName"/>
      <!-- i'm trying to get customer name and assign that on to my model -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function DemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.content = [
    {
        name: "Bireysel",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: "Kurumsal",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Bireysel & Kurumsal",
        id: 3
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see demo below
In select change your model to cutomer and in inputs use customer.id customer.name

```js
function DemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.content = [{
    name: "Bireysel",
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: "Kurumsal",
    id: 2
  }, {
    name: "Bireysel & Kurumsal",
    id: 3
  }];

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <select ng-model="customer" ng-options="item as item.name for item in content" ng-change="customerName = item.name">
    </select>

    <br/>
    <input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customer.id" />
    <input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customer.name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mate how could i assign selected option from javascript, i've tested here and failed: https://jsfiddle.net/507zzvmk/12/

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="customer" ng-options="item.name for item in content">
```

and

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customer.id"/>
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customer.name"/>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/507zzvmk/3/)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
Please Check this.This will resolve your problem
Once you select from DROPDOWN the selected Object will be stored in `customer`. Then this `customer` object contains `id` as well as `name`

**MISTAKE you have made is**

```
     ng-model="customerId"  ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in content"
```

Here ONLY `item.id` will be collected to `customerId`

If you want whole object then DO LIKE BELOW

```
    <div ng-app>
     <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <select ng-model="customer" ng-options="item.name for item in content" ng-change="customerName = item.name">
       </select>
       <br/>
       <input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customer.id"/>
       <input disabled="disabled" type="text" ng-model="customer.name"/>
     </div>
     </div>
```