# how to display a return value from sql into a selectbox

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

i have multiple select boxes in a table.i have a function that gets me data from sql

```
self.GetDetails = function ()
    {
        var params = {//pass parameters
                     };
        return Ajax.Get(self.$http,
              {
                  url:Details,
                  params: params,
                  success: function (data)
                  { 
                      self.Details = data.data;
                  }
              });
    }
```

which works and i get the following output example: *`category:Milk`*

how do i take this category and display it in a select box,in the select box i have multiple categories but if im retrieving data back i want that data to be displayed. right now it only shows me the default value

```
      <tr ng-repeat="Request in Module"  >
         <td ng-form="form"><select ng-model="Request.CategoryID"  ng-options="category.CategoryID as category.CategoryDescription for category in Module.RequestReasons" >
                        <option  default value="">Reasons</option></select>
         </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: what was the need to down vote me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031394/how-to-assign-selected-options-text-to-another-model-while-using-ng-options/29032227#29032227

Please find answer.

Comment: but i dont want it to be displayed in a seperate textbox,it must get displayed in the selectbox ,so milk should be displaed in the selectbox so that if the user wants to change the request they can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple select boxes in a table and you already know the value that the user choosed,at a later stage  to display the data back in a selectbox you  would use the ng-init option so it would be

```
<select ng-init="Request.CategoryID=Request.CategoryDescription " ng-model="Request.CategoryID"  ng-options="category.CategoryID as category.CategoryDescription for category in Module.RequestReasons" >
                    <option  default value="">Reasons</option></select>
```