# How to add an element at first of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object:

```
TICKET_PRIORITIES: {
    LOW: 'low',
    NORMAL: 'normal',
    HIGH: 'high',
    VERY_HIGH: 'very high'
}
```

In client side I have to add select at first.

Result I wanted to be

```
TICKET_PRIORITIES: {
    SELECT: 'select',    
    LOW: 'low',
    NORMAL: 'normal',
    HIGH: 'high',
    VERY_HIGH: 'very high'
}
```

```
<select ng-model="selectedPriority" ng-options="key as key | translate for (key, value) in priorities" class="form-control m-b"> </select>
```

In this select I wanna select "select" option and select option should be at the first of drop down.

Comment: Please refer [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691409/add-new-element-at-the-beginning-of-a-json

Comment: Object items are disordered. So there is nothing called *first element* in objects.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by attempting this, because your understanding of JS objects is wrong. Perhaps we can help figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Syms I refered your link. Thanks for posting.

My problem is different. 

<select ng-model="selectedPriority" ng-options="key as key | translate for (key, value) in priorities" class="form-control m-b">
</select>

In this select I wanna select "select" option and select option should be at the first of drop down.

Comment: Tresdin - please give some references and explain your comment. In object, elements will maintain in disorder way?

Comment: Babu Veera Konchem ardham ayyela cheppandi @Veera

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031394/how-to-assign-selected-options-text-to-another-model-while-using-ng-options/29032227#29032227

Please Check the reference .Here is my Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var TICKET_PRIORITIES = {
    LOW: 'low',
    NORMAL: 'normal',
    HIGH: 'high',
    VERY_HIGH: 'very high'
  };
TICKET_PRIORITIES['SELECT']='select';
alert(JSON.stringify(TICKET_PRIORITIES));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o1hk4kLm/)**

Comment: as per my requirement select should come at first Ozil. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @ Veera This is an `object` not `array` that will cause `index` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Object properties order are not concerned while creating object but you can create new properties like:

```
TICKET_PRIORITIES = {
    LOW: 'low',
    NORMAL: 'normal',
    HIGH: 'high',
    VERY_HIGH: 'very high'
  }

TICKET_PRIORITIES.SELECT='select';
```

Comment: As per my requirement select should come at first Mytri. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Veera you want a array or object?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible**. Javascript does not care about or enforce the order of properties in objects (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) for reference). Or, to quote the ECMAscript standard (emphasis mine):

> **4.3.3 Object** 
>   An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

If order is important to you, you will need a different data structure using arrays, e.g. something like this:

```
TICKET_PRIORITIES: [
    {id: "LOW", label: "low"},
    {id: "NORMAL", label: "normal"},
    {id: "HIGH", label: "high"},
    {id: "VERY_HIGH", label: "very high"}
]
```

This allows you to do something like this (`unshift` adds an element to the beginng of an array):

```
TICKET_PRIORITIES.unshift({id: "SELECT", label: "select"})
```